# How to make dictionary of alphabet and scrambled alphabet?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to create multiple dictionaries for another program using the alphabet as the key and a scrambled alphabet (the first one I have to do is BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO) as the value. This is what I have so far but it says "unhashable type: 'list'"

```
_list = input("Enter list: ")

alpha = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

dict1 = {}

for i in range(0,len(_list)):
     dict1[alpha][i] == _list[i]

print(dict1)
```

Comment: convert to tuple to use as a dict key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your code.

1. `dict1[alpha][i]` should be `dict1[alpha[i]]`

As pointed out by Paul Rooney, you cannot use a `list` as a dictionary key, but I don't think that is what you are trying to do. Instead, you just want the `ith` element of the list `alpha`.

2. the `==` should be `=`.

`==` is used to compare, `=` is used to assign a value.

Also, the pythonic way to do your iteration is as follows:

```
dict1 = {alpha[idx]: character for idx, character in enumerate(_list)}
```

which is the equivalent of

```
dict1 = {}
for idx, character in enumerate(_list):
    dict1[alpha[idx]] = character
```